# Split substrings on a single delimiter while adding unique text markers

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

In my XSLT, I have used tokens to split substrings on a single delimiter (,) however how do I place a unique text to mark each substring? Thank you.

Example, XML document:

```
<list>1,4,7,9</list>
```

Desired output:

```
<w>1</w>
<x>4</x>
<y>7</y>
<z>9</z>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XSLT 1.0 solution works for your example.

It recursively splits your input at a delimiter character and assigns individual parts to elements named according to a list you also supply as a parameter.

When either individual input parts or element names run out (whatever happens first), recursion stops.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="list">
    <xsl:call-template name="split">
      <xsl:with-param name="input" select="." />
      <xsl:with-param name="elems" select="'w,x,y,z'" />
      <xsl:with-param name="delim" select="','" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="split">
    <xsl:param name="input" select="''" />
    <xsl:param name="elems" select="''" />
    <xsl:param name="delim" select="','" />

    <xsl:if test="$elems != '' and $input != '' and $delim != ''">
      <xsl:variable name="curr-part" select="substring-before( concat($input, $delim), $delim)" />
      <xsl:variable name="curr-elem" select="substring-before( concat($elems, $delim), $delim)" />
      <xsl:element name="{$curr-elem}">
        <xsl:value-of select="$curr-part" />
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:call-template name="split">
        <xsl:with-param name="input" select="substring-after($input, concat($curr-part, $delim))" />
        <xsl:with-param name="elems" select="substring-after($elems, concat($curr-elem, $delim))" />
        <xsl:with-param name="delim" select="$delim" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This template produces, with your input of `<list>1,4,7,9</list>`:

```
<w>1</w><x>4</x><y>7</y><z>9</z>
```

Note that the sample output is lacking a document element and therefore is not a valid XML document.

Comment: Thanks for responding Tomalak, for some reason it is not concatenating properly, I am just getting 1479 for some reason hmm

Comment: @Andres Charles: I've tested my code and it works. Maybe you make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: @Andres Did you find the problem?

Comment: thanks for asking, I used select="string('w,x,y,z')", instead of writing it the normal way, for some reason it started rendering okay. Its XSLT 1.0.

Comment: @Andres: `select="string('w,x,y,z')"` is equivalent to `select="'w,x,y,z'"`. It will work either way.

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification of the previous answer allows you to create unique element ids based on generate-id and the index of the delimited value....

```
<xsl:template match="list">
    <xsl:call-template name="split">
        <xsl:with-param name="input" select="." />
        <xsl:with-param name="delim" select="','" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="split">
    <xsl:param name="input" select="''" />
    <xsl:param name="index"  select="1" />
    <xsl:param name="delim" select="','" />

    <xsl:if test="$input != '' and $delim != ''">
        <xsl:variable name="curr-input" select="substring-before( concat($input, $delim), $delim)" />
        <xsl:element name="{concat(generate-id(.),'-',$index)}">
            <xsl:value-of select="$curr-input" />
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:call-template name="split">
            <xsl:with-param name="input" select="substring-after($input, concat($curr-input, $delim))" />
            <xsl:with-param name="index"  select="$index + 1" />
            <xsl:with-param name="delim" select="$delim" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

This allows you generate nodes that are unique without having to supply a list of node names...the result set would be:
`<d0e3-1>1</d0e3-1><d0e3-2>2</d0e3-2><d0e3-3>3</d0e3-3><d0e3-4>4</d0e3-4>`